# how do I "checkout" from a remote mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I am setting up a dedicated build server, which needs to checkout (either the tip, or ideally the head of a specific branch) from a remote hg server (served by hg serve).

If possible I want to avoid cloning the entire repository as I'm using docker and want to keep the containers as small as possible and simply checkout the latest/named branch.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038573/mercurial-how-do-you-export-your-repos-source-to-a-production-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running hgweb, which you are if you're using `hg serve`, then you have access to archive URLs like: /archive/tip.tar.gz , which gets you a tarball of the tip.  For example Mercurial's own repo's tip.tar.gz is at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/tip.tar.gz

It's important to note that this *isn't* a clone.  You can't do local hg commands on that -- you can't `hg tag` or `hg id` or any of the usual things builds systems like to do.

More normal is to keep a local clone outside the docker container and share that fs into the container for building.  That's what we're doing at work.

Comment: That's perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Do you have a link to any documentation on the various formats of the archive url?

Comment: You can see a lot of examples by checking out the links in hgweb itself, but anytihng that can identify a revision can be used.  So /archive/branchname.tar.gz would get you the latest head in that branch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get *only needed* revision in **any** DVCS and with remote Mercurial repository you can do nothing, only clone to local repository.

But your task is slightly different: you have to have *some deploy tool*, which transfer latest changes from repository-host to build-host - and this operation must be performed (if you want to avoid cloning totally) **on repository's side**. I.e you can (if you have rights) `hg archive` (or, with extensions - `hg exportfiles`|`hg ftp`) needed changeset from repository onto some temporary tree and transfer (using any possible technique - ftp, scp, rsync) to final target on build-server

Comment: Many thanks, I now get that "hg archive" is the command I was looking for. Shame it can't be run remotely, but a simple script will do just as well.